# Do users care if avatars have a style of opacity on hover?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

I have a site that allows users to watch movies. Users can send friend requests to see what movies their friends like. I have made this feature convenient by putting some of their friends avatars on the movie covers. You can then click on their profile and view their likes and friends. Before they click, they hover and the opacity of the avatar is reduced. **Are users ok with this?**

On some movie covers, an object is going through the friends head or the lighting is ruined due to the background? Or in some cases, the logo of the movie is streaming through their head. Do users understand this or does it ruin the experience? In other words, does it destroy the virtual reality and make the users think:

> These aren't **real** people. These are images on a movie cover.

[image: Visual Aid of Project]

**Note:** My screenshot application hides the mouse cursor.

Comment: Since you have a testable system, a pretty good option is for you to test it with users, see if they're ok with it, and let us know what you find out.

Comment: @KenMohnkern I haven't launched the site yet. In a general sense, do users care?

Comment: I don't think they care in the sense that you're suggesting but it does send a mixed message about the clickability of the avatars - if something dims or becomes more transparent on hover they we generally assume that it's not available

Comment: I don't understand why it matters if they care or not? You have a lot of blue in your design, does it matter if your users hate the colour blue?

Comment: @CodePlay, there's no need to wait for launch before testing. Just sit with a few people individually and watch them use your site on your dev server. I doubt they're going to be confused by the avatars, but we can't know for certain.

Comment: Before asking "_does it destroy the virtual reality_" and makes users think "_these aren't real people_" I'd want to see some pretty compelling evidence that users thought they _were_ real people in the first place! On a practical note, I would think making an avatar _more_ opaque when you hover over it (so that it is more clearly distinguishable from the background) would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differance in tone between an avatar and a movie cover could be quite jarring. Consider a blue(cold) image over a red and yellow(warm) cover. Perhaps better to consider some of the options to increase contrast, such as a vignette or gradient over the movie cover to allow the user icons to stand out.

If you want the movie covers to stand out to the user and not the avatars, I wouldn't recommend putting it over the top at all.

Comment: Great ideas. I think I'm going to get rid of the opacity change and make the avatar scale instead. I want the avatars to stand out with the movie covers because the avatars are associated with the movie cover.